# Column to Row transpose in Talend

Tags: talend

I want to get a crosstable operation by using Talend Open studio.

My Source is like:

```
    id   201601    201602    201603    ...
    1    aa        bb        cc         ...
```

I want to get the output like below:

```
id    date      value
1     201601    aa
1     201602    bb
1     201603    cc
.     .         .
.     .         .
.     .         .
```

Column name is depend on date. So I need a automatic way to convert columns into rows.

Comment: Please show what you've tried - and have a read of [Ask]

Answer (score 2):

You may use tSplitRow.
See the capture with the job, tSplitRow configura and schema.
[image]

Comment: Thank for your help.But there are 60 columns in my table. And the column name is a date string like "201601","201602". So i need a automatic way to deal with my request

Answer (score 1):

I think  you can try with tUnpivotRow component. However you need to know this is custom component created by community member daztop.
Component is avalaible to download [from this link.](https://exchange.talend.com/#marketplaceproductoverview:marketplace=marketplace%252F1&p=marketplace%252F1%252Fproducts%252F737&pi=marketplace%252F1%252Fproducts%252F737%252Fitems%252F1043)

Under [this link](https://community.talend.com/t5/Troubleshooting-Installation/Converting-columns-to-rows/ta-p/21658) you will find instruction how to use this component.

Also if your data are stored in database you can transpose columns to rows direclty in that database by running proper sql query via talend (query depends from databse engine).